# What plugin will allow me to redirect 404 errors to a specific page?

Tags: plugins

What plugin will allow me to redirect 404 errors to a specific WP page...and track all 404 errors?

I'd like to just use a plugin that will redirect without having to edit templates and such.

Answer (score 3):

add these to your function.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_redirect', 1 );
function custom_redirect() {
    $direction = get_permalink( 12 ); // Or whatever the page_id is ...
    if ( is_404() ) wp_redirect( $direction );
}
```

There. But it still not tracking the 404 errors. Unless you add more specific codes in the function which counts all the redirection or on the destination page for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 404 page by creating a file in your theme called `404.php` and filling that with whatever you want to be shown on a page that WordPress can't find. You can [read more about Creating an Error 404 Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) in the Codex.

Alternatively if you wanted to redirect users back to your home page instead you could create a 404 file in you theme as above with the following:

```
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
     <title>404 - Page not found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>Error 404 - Sorry the page you are looking for could not be found</h1>
     <h2>You will be redirected to the homepage in a few moments.</h2>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Well, I created a regular page in WP and I would like users to find this page which uses a template from my theme....instead of a 404.

Comment: You could use the above code, but change the countdown to 0 and replace the url with `<?php echo get_permalink(1); ?>` where 1 was the page ID you want to redirect users to.

Comment: I really like what you're saying! So...Where is the countdown? Would you mind posting the entire code you recommend for redirecting to a specific wordpress page?